# Get connection strings in ARM

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I'm creating an Azure Resource Manager template that instantiates multiple resources.

I'd like to be able to capture the primary connection strings of 
Redis , AzureWebJobsDashboard, AzureWebJobsStorage and AzureWebJobsServiceBus.

Comment: Any update?If you feel my answer is useful /helpful. Please mark it as an answer so that other folks could benefit from it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could use the ARM Template Function [`ListKeys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#listkeys) to get the Keys. And we could use the following template code to set the connection string.

Here is a demo I capture the Redis, Storage, Service Bus connectionstring and add it to the web application settings.

Since AzureWebJobsDashboard, AzureWebJobsStorage is storage connection string, AzureWebJobsServiceBus is service Bus root manager connection string.

So in my template, I directly get the connection string according to the storage and service bus name.

1.Create Basic Azure Resource Group project with template WebApp

2.From demo remove the unnecessary resource.

3.Add the connection string setting

```json
"resources": [
        {
          "name": "connectionstrings",
          "type": "config",
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webSiteName'))]"
          ],
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "tomConnectionString"
          },
          "properties": {

            "storage": {
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',parameters('storageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',concat(listKeys(variables('storageAccountId'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1))]",
              "type": "Custom"
            },

            "Redis": {
              "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Cache/Redis', variables('RedisName')), '2016-04-01').primaryKey]",
              "type": "Custom"
            },

            "ServiceBus": {
              "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/AuthorizationRules',parameters('serviceBusNamespace'),'RootManageSharedAccessKey'),'2015-08-01').primaryConnectionString]",
              "type": "Custom"
            }

          }
        }
      ]
```

4.Add the corresponding parameters or variables such as storage info or service bus name.

5.Deploy the template

The result is as below:

[image]

Full template code:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "hostingPlanName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "skuName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "S1",
      "allowedValues": [
        "F1",
        "D1",
        "B1",
        "B2",
        "B3",
        "S1",
        "S2",
        "S3",
        "P1",
        "P2",
        "P3",
        "P4"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's pricing tier and instance size. Check details at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/"
      }
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Storage Account to access blob storage."
      }
    },

    "serviceBusNamespace": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "access service bus."
      }
    },
    "skuCapacity": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 1,
      "minValue": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's instance count"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "webSiteName": "[concat('webSite', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
    "RedisName": "brando",
    
    "storageAccountId": "[concat(resourceGroup().id,'/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "HostingPlan"
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('skuName')]",
        "capacity": "[parameters('skuCapacity')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "Website"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      },

      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "connectionstrings",
          "type": "config",
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webSiteName'))]"
          ],
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "tomConnectionString"
          },
          "properties": {

            "storage": {
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',parameters('storageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',concat(listKeys(variables('storageAccountId'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1))]",
              "type": "Custom"
            },

            "Redis": {
              "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Cache/Redis', variables('RedisName')), '2016-04-01').primaryKey]",
              "type": "Custom"
            },

            "ServiceBus": {
              "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/AuthorizationRules',parameters('serviceBusNamespace'),'RootManageSharedAccessKey'),'2015-08-01').primaryConnectionString]",
              "type": "Custom"
            }

          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Default connection string also ends with `;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net`

Comment: ^^ you'll want to be sure to consider Azure Cloud Environments (Sovereign Clouds like China, Germany, USGovm,etc and Azure Stack) when specifying those endpoints. More info: https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/src/ResourceManagement/ResourceManager/AzureEnvironment.cs